# creating multiple R dataframe dynamically importing from the file directory contains sas datasets

Tags: r

Need your help , I am new to R.
The scenario is have a list of sas datasets in the specfic locations.

```
path <- 'C:\\XXXX\\XXX'
files <- list.files(path = path,pattern="*.sas7bdat", full.names=FALSE)
```

the **files** variable gives the list of files names available in that directory.

i am keeping the file name as the dataframe using split function removing the extensions stored in **domain_name** variable.
Iterating each filename which his the sas dataset importing and create each dataset name dynamically.(for instance if there are 30 sas datasets, 30 R dataframes should be created.

```
library(haven)
for (i in 1:length(files)){ 
  domain_name=strsplit(i,split='.sas7bdat', fixed=TRUE)
  domain_name <- read_sas(data_file=paste(path,i,sep='/'))
}
```

could you explain the concept and fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use a list: `domain_name[[i]] <- read...`

Comment: Thanks, its giving the NULL value, I am trying to generated individual dataframe based on the file listed in the directory? what may be the reason

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. I don't understand, what exactly your problem is: what is giving NULL?

Comment: domain_name[[i]]<- read_sas(data_file=paste(path,i,sep='/')) as u suggested, its not assigning and creating the new data frame dynamically within the loop. when i print(domain_name[[i]]) its returning NULL. what i need to do further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should in principle work. As there is no real example I can only guess.

```
path <- 'C:/path2file/'
print(path)
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern="*.sas7bdat", full.names=FALSE)
print(files)

mydf <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  filename <- paste0(path, files[i])
  print(filename)
  # browser() # if you like to step through the file
  mydf[[i]] <- haven::read_sas(data_file=filename)
  print(names(mydf[[i]]))
  eval(parse(text = paste0("mydf_", i, " <- haven::read_sas(data_file=filename)")))
}
```

Then you can access each data.frame via e.g. `df1 <- mydf[[1]]`

Comment: thanks .its creating a large list , but i am looking for each individual sas datasets to a R dataframe. is the below is fine?
mydf[i]= pd.DataFrame(mydf)

Comment: @Rod I added another solution, but this is not, how R is intended to work... It should create a lot of dataframes.

Comment: Apology for late response well that is my requirement . Thanks for the code. Could you get me the each data frame name as the file name like if the sas dataset name is "aa.sas7bdat" the data fame should be "aa".
I am trying to use domain name=strsplit(i,split='.sas7bdat', fixed=TRUE) this statement buts not able to recognize it.

Comment: Thanks for the code again,its not solved .I am getting this error ,
Error in parse(text = paste0(filename, " <- haven::read_sas(data_file=filename)")) : 
  <text>:1:1: unexpected '/'
i think filename is printing the fullpath, 
Could you get me the each data frame name as the file name like if the sas dataset name is "aa.sas7bdat" the data fame should be "aa".

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thanks for your help